# Styling what's shipped in the slot element

Tags: web-component, styling, custom-element, slot, lit-element

My request is weird, since I used another approach that totally worked and is way more clean. However, SEO called and told me, my kind of structure isn't really googlebot-friendly.

So here is the situation (please don't judge it, I know there are other ways to do what I try to achieve, by not using childfragments at all):

This is my component:

```
class Container extends LitElement {
  static get tagName() {
    return 'container';
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css`
      ${unsafeCSS(styles)}
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <article class="o-container">
        <slot></slot>
      </article>
    `;
  }
}

defineOnce(Container.tagName, Container);

export default Container;
```

This is how I use it:

```
  <footer>
    <div class="o-footer__collection">
      <div class="o-footer__main">
        <h1 class="o-footer__title-desktop">
          me & me
        </h1>
        <button
          class="o-footer__accordion-button"
        >
          <h1 class="o-footer__title">
            you & you
          </h1>
          <span
            class="o-footer__accordion-button-caret o-footer__accordion-button-caret--open"
          >
            blabla
          </span>
        </button>
        <ul
          class="o-footer__main-content-panel o-footer__main-content-panel--open"
        >
          <li
            class="o-footer__main-content-panel-list-item"
          >
            <a
              href="https://google.com"
              target="_blank"
              >Contact</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </footer>
```

You see, all those children land within the `slot` area of the component. Initially, those children were part of the component and had a styling. Now they are outside of it and the styling no longer gets applied. Does anyone know how to get around this problem? I found in the docs, that you could use the ::slotted() css attribute, but apparently that one doesn't seem to work. Or did I probably do something else wrong? I also tried to put the style-tag into the `render` html, but that only has minor impacts.

I don't know which route I should focus on. Any help is appreciated. IMHO the styling should be part of the component itself and not up to the guy using the component. But that slot element broke everything, although the rest of the structure is still the same.

Comment: where is the <container> tag and where is the CSS ?

Comment: And Web Components must use a dash in their component name. `container` is invalid but `my-container`, `container-one` or `special-container` are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The ::slotted syntax will work with a disclaimer I will explain after this. If you want all text inside p tags within your slot to be green the syntax would be:

```
::slotted(p) {
  color: green;
}
```

The disclaimer is that this is not part of the ShadowDom so it is not protected. i.e., the host document can still override the css. Elements inside the slot are considered to be in the "light DOM".

To have control over the elements inside the slot you can approach this using one of the lifecycle events. For example:

```
firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      const paras = document.querySelector("test-element").querySelectorAll('p');

      [].forEach.call(paras, (e)=>{
        e.style.color = "green";
      });
});
```

Inside the firstUpdated handler you can programmatically style the slot contents. Not the requestAnimation frame. I reference the following gitHub discussion for this https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/338. The context of that discussion is a web component inside the slot of another web component, but I think it may be good practice to do this because the slot elements may not be fully rendered when the custom component firstUpdated gets fired.

Comment: I know I am kind of a hardliner on this, but using js to do styling stuff is hardly ever appropriate and it's always a performance and UX sacrifice. But still thanks for your answer, I also know that not everything can be done with CSS as of now. I'm trying another approach now, where the slotted children are always "base elements" without children. Still not that cool, but it seems to work so far.